# Iterate in oracle using incremental iterable variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get some data iteratively from an Oracle database. Here's a skeleton of the query I'm trying:

```
select a.id, a.cd,
       sum(case
               when b.count>0
                    then b.count+1
               when b.count=0
                    then 1
                    else 0
            end),
        sum(case
               when b.count>0 and b.received is NULL and c.rid is NULL
                    then b.count+1
               when b.count=0 and b.received is NULL and c.rid is NULL\
                    then 1
                    else 0
            end),
         sum(case
               when c.err='Y'
               then 1
               else 0
            end),
         max(b.sent)
   from
       b 
   left join c 
        on b.oid=c.oid
       inner join a
        on b.id=a.id
       inner join d
        on (d.oid=b.oid
           and d.tss=
                 (select max(tss)
                  from e where rid=b.rid
                         and rcd=b.rcd))
    where b.sent is not null
          /* !!!  The line below !!! */
          and b.sent > sysdate -2*i/24 and b.sent <= sysdate -2*(i-1)/24
          and b.id=7
    group by a.id,a.cd
    order by a.id
```

Please notice the highlighted part `and b.sent > sysdate -2*i/24 and b.sent <= sysdate -2*(i-1)/24`. This is where I want to iterate incrementing the value of i each time. I tried putting this in a for loop incrementing the value of i each time but got the error

> "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement".

When I tried to declare variables and put the results of the select statement into them, I was unable to due to the group by statements. I'm getting stuck at this point hence reaching out to the members for the expert help. Thank you for patiently going through this. Please do let me know if there is a way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you thought about executable code block?

Comment: So you have a query and a loop.  What are you going to do with the results of the query within the loop?  The `PLS-00428` error is telling you that you need to tell Oracle to do something with the results of the query.  Either fetch the data into some local variables (scalar variables or collections depending on whether the query returns multiple rows) or loop through the results of the query in a cursor.  Of course, if you're in a PL/SQL block, it would be odd to want to iterate through results by changing parameters rather than just iterating through results in a cursor.

Comment: Thank you @TS for taking the time out to go through this. Let me check out executable code block and see if it can help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Justin Cave for taking the time out to go through this and the suggestion. I should have mentioned the reason I'm trying to do this exercise. The query pasted above gives data for the last couple of hours (when i=1).  I'm trying to get historical data by iteration so for instance when I'd increment i by 1 the timestamp would change to get the data between 4 and 2 hours ago. Similarly trying to get a sizeable dataset which will then help in applying time series to predict with some accuracy... (concluded in the next comment)

Comment: (Continuing from the previous comment).. I understand that a cursor will get rows of data through which we iterate. However, here we get one row of data over every iteration. Hence a cursor might not be the solution here.

Comment: If you're getting a single row, then you'd fetch into a local scalar variable in your loop.  But it would seem to make more sense to write a single query that returns all the data you want and simply aggregate by the hour or by the two hour block or however else you want to aggregate the data.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an explicit loop if you just want to execute some query for subsequent values of parameter. You can generate a sequence of values and use lateral join (in Oracle 12+) for each row:

> ```
> create table t
> as
>   select level as l
>     , sysdate + trunc(level / 5) as v
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 13
> ```

> ```
> with a as (
>   select level as i
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 6
> )
> select
>   a.i as iter,
>   t2.*
> from a
>   outer apply (
>     select *
>     from t
>     where v between sysdate - i
>       and sysdate + i
>   ) t2
> ```
>
> ```
> ITER |  L | V        
> ---: | -: | :--------
>    1 |  1 | 19-APR-21
>    1 |  2 | 19-APR-21
>    1 |  3 | 19-APR-21
>    1 |  4 | 19-APR-21
>    1 |  5 | 20-APR-21
>    1 |  6 | 20-APR-21
>    1 |  7 | 20-APR-21
>    1 |  8 | 20-APR-21
>    1 |  9 | 20-APR-21
>    2 |  1 | 19-APR-21
>    2 |  2 | 19-APR-21
>    2 |  3 | 19-APR-21
>    2 |  4 | 19-APR-21
>    2 |  5 | 20-APR-21
>    2 |  6 | 20-APR-21
>    2 |  7 | 20-APR-21
>    2 |  8 | 20-APR-21
>    2 |  9 | 20-APR-21
>    2 | 10 | 21-APR-21
>    2 | 11 | 21-APR-21
>    2 | 12 | 21-APR-21
>    3 |  1 | 19-APR-21
>    3 |  2 | 19-APR-21
>    3 |  3 | 19-APR-21
>    3 |  4 | 19-APR-21
>    3 |  5 | 20-APR-21
>    3 |  6 | 20-APR-21
>    3 |  7 | 20-APR-21
>    3 |  8 | 20-APR-21
>    3 |  9 | 20-APR-21
>    3 | 10 | 21-APR-21
>    3 | 11 | 21-APR-21
>    3 | 12 | 21-APR-21
>    4 |  1 | 19-APR-21
>    4 |  2 | 19-APR-21
>    4 |  3 | 19-APR-21
>    4 |  4 | 19-APR-21
>    4 |  5 | 20-APR-21
>    4 |  6 | 20-APR-21
>    4 |  7 | 20-APR-21
>    4 |  8 | 20-APR-21
>    4 |  9 | 20-APR-21
>    4 | 10 | 21-APR-21
>    4 | 11 | 21-APR-21
>    4 | 12 | 21-APR-21
>    5 |  1 | 19-APR-21
>    5 |  2 | 19-APR-21
>    5 |  3 | 19-APR-21
>    5 |  4 | 19-APR-21
>    5 |  5 | 20-APR-21
>    5 |  6 | 20-APR-21
>    5 |  7 | 20-APR-21
>    5 |  8 | 20-APR-21
>    5 |  9 | 20-APR-21
>    5 | 10 | 21-APR-21
>    5 | 11 | 21-APR-21
>    5 | 12 | 21-APR-21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1c5eb34e73343a1370ca4c22f4e507d3)*